# How to make QSslSocket support SSL using an OpenSSL installation?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, openssl

I'm trying to run a simple client/server to implement a communication using QSslSocket. I work on Windows (unfortunately) and I use QtCreator for more convenience.

When I try, from the client side, to connect to the server using `MyQSslSocket->connectToHostEncrypted(ip, port)`, I get the following message:

> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed

When I print the raised error, I get the following one:

> QAbstractSocket::SocketError(20)

In the documentation we can find that this error code corresponds to `QAbstractSocket::SslInternalError` whose the description is:

> "The SSL library being used reported an internal error. This is probably the result of a bad installation or misconfiguration of the library."

After some investigations I found that Qt does not provide OpenSSL by itself so I installed it (the binaries, for both 32 and 64 bits versions to be sure) from here https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html.
During the installation, the dll was copied to C:\Windows\System32 (for the 64 bits). Then I checked that the `PATH` environment variable does well contain this folder.

At this point I tried again, but I still had the same problem, as if the OpenSSL installation was still not found.

When I print the output of the following calls (in the main function of my client):

```
qDebug() << QSslSocket::supportsSsl();
qDebug() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
```

I get the following outputs:

> false
> ""

My question is, how to make `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` return true ?

If anyone could teach me what I missed, what I am doing wrong and tell me what I should do to be able to make this SSL connection run properly, I would be very grateful.

Fareanor.

PS: Sorry for the long question but I think it is important to clearly expose the problem and the context to help you to easily understand the problem and give me more relevant answers.

Comment: What versions of Qt are you using? and what version of ssl are you using? 1.0.x or 1.1.x? IIRC ssl 1.1.x might be supported only by recent Qt versions. It might be worth trying using ssl 1.0.x

Comment: Oh I didn't know it. My version of Qt is 5.12.2 and my version of OpenSSL is 1.1.1b. I have taken the latest I could. Do you think I have to downgrade my OpenSSL installation ? If possible, I prefer avoid doing it because I want to be up-to-date in term of security features...

Comment: I'm not an expert of SSL however in terms of security you should be safe with latest 1.0.2 patch level. Do try to download the 1.0 version and place the libs in your binary dir. This should be enough to test if it worls

Comment: @Fareanor check the version of openSsl that your Qt package uses: `qDebug() << "SslLibraryBuildVersion: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();` Then you should install the closest version and put `libeay32.dll, libssl32.dll and ssleay32.dll` next to your *.exe

Comment: Yes, that was the idea I had after the answer of @Alienpenguin but I didn't find the time to do it. I'll come back once done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
Thanks to @AlienPenguin and @Macias advices, it was that my version of OpenSSL was too recent.

Finally I have installed the closest available version of the one used for the Qt build (which does make sense, I should have thought of it) which can be found by running the following call:

```
qDebug() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
```

Problem solved.

Thanks again.