# Qt error message "qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed"

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, openssl

I get the following error when I try to run my Qt application:

> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
>   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
>   Error:  "TLS initialization failed"

My application is really basic here is what it is look like:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QNetworkReply>

#include <QDebug>


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    netManager  = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    netReply = nullptr;
    mDataBuffer = new QByteArray();

    //Define network request
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.qt.io"));

    netReply = netManager->get(request);
    connect(netReply,&QIODevice::readyRead,this,&Widget::dataReadyToRead);
    connect(netReply,&QNetworkReply::finished,this,&Widget::dataReadFinished);

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::dataReadyToRead()
{
    qDebug() << "Datas available to read";
    mDataBuffer->append(netReply->readAll());
}

void Widget::dataReadFinished()
{
    if(netReply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << netReply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        ui->textEdit->setPlainText(QString(*mDataBuffer));
    }
}
```

So I searched on stack overflow and find some answers (it seems that the error occurs because the openSSl librairies are not found) but it still doesn't work.
So here is what I've done so far:

- I've downloaded OpenSSL for window 64 bit (Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1d) on this website: 
      https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
- I've installed OpenSSL
  (- Try to set environment variables but I didn't manage to do it correctly)
- Try to run my app while running openSSL

Did I miss something?

Edit:

Thanks for the reply:

Here is what is get from the qDebugs:

- QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString() returned: "OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018"
- QSslSocket::supportsSsl() returned: false
- QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString() returned: an empty string

So here is I've grab and install OpenSSL in 1.0.2 version, (unistall the other one), add to the PATH variable the install folder (which is simply C:\OpenSSL-Win64, also tried C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin both of those file cotains dll)

Unfortunately I still have the same problem.

Installation folder content:

- bin
- exp
- include
- lib
- changes.txt
- faq.txt
- libeay32.dll
- libssl.dll
- license.txt
- news.txt
- readme.txt
- ssleay32.dll
- unins000.dat
- unins000.exe

Now I've tried to do somethings after I've read Qt documentation:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html

- I copy/paste the directory OpenSSL-Win64 in C:\Windows\System32 (according to the documentation the openSSL libraries are looked first in this directory)-> didn't work
- I've created a PATH environment variable and give it the value of the openSSL installation folder (for now I've use the 'Path' environment variable created by default, it has override the default value but I've manage to restore it)-> didn't work

Comment: Not sure but it may be the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027731/11455384

Comment: Can you show the contents of your OpenSSL installation directory ? Same thing for the bin directory ? If the `QSslSocket::supportsSSL()` still returns `false` and you get an empty string when querying the actual installed version, this means that your OpenSSL installation is still not found. Check that you've included **all** the directory that contains dlls (I mentioned the bin directory but sometimes there is a lib directory that contains some needed dlls too), don't get stuck of the example I give to you (don't be passive).

Comment: Don't worry I'm not passive I've already tried many things. In fact the app that I've made is from a tutorial that I've followed along. In this tutorial the 'teacher' adds a note about somme warning you can get with ssl etc... (just warning not errros).
So I've already did many things: download many openSSL librairies, each times install them, tried to create environment variables and/or copy and paste dll in the Qt folders each times, remade this project  4 times with differents kits. It is just that at this point I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Regarding your last edit... You don't have to copy-paste the folder, only the dlls must be put in C:\Windows\System32 for this solution (this is the one I use and it works fine). For the PATH solution, you don't have to create a PATH, you have to **append to the existing path the dll folders**. In fact I'm afraid you don't really know what you are doing, you should take some time to learn how dynamic linking works. Then if you did things well, and still not work, maybe you've downloaded 32 bits version instead of 64bits. Or maybe you are compiling your app with a 32bits kit instead of 64 one.

Comment: You should have read this line on your link: _"The OpenSSL libraries are looked up first in the directory of the executable, then in the Windows System directory (usually C:\Windows\system32), and finally in all directories listed in the PATH environment variable."_ Choose one of these solutions and apply it with exactitude (none of your tries was correct).

Comment: By the way, when installing OpenSSL, there is a checkbox that propose you to install the dlls in System32 automatically.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've dowloaded the 64bits version and that I compiling with 64bts compiler (I've checked the kit tha tI'm using).
For the line of the doc you quote I've already read it thats why I've tried to copy and paste the OpenSSL folder in C:\Windows\Window32.
And for the PATH variable, yes I've made a mistake because I've tied many time to append to the existing path dll folders.
In fact I have dll files in OpenSSL-Win64 and in OpenSSL-WIn64\bin so I've tried to append only one of those files or the two files at the same time.

Comment: I will try to unistall OpenSSL to see for the checkbox you mentionned. Btw once thanks again for your reponses.

Comment: OK, I will re-install OpenSSL and check 'Copy OpenSSL DLLs to: The Windows system directory'. And I can confirm that 64bits version for OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution (that worked for me):

- Check which version of OpenSSL was used for the Qt build with qDebug (see Fareanor answer).
- Download a close version of OpenSSl for Windows 64 bits as it is my OS.
- Execute the downloaded installer **and check 'Copy OpenSSL DLLs to: The Windows system directory' checkbox**.

Comment: Another Windows note:  Just went through this with a Qt 5.15.0 application.  Deploying libssl and libcrypto DLL's along with the application worked.  To help get the right version, choose the OpenSSL libraries which are loaded with QtCreator.

In my case C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL....

In my case it happened to be 1.1.1j and they worked fine for the deployed application.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the information provided on the question, it looks like you have installed a too recent OpenSSL version. In fact I already had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55992841).

As you've found out, Qt does not embed OpenSSL. What you have to do is to install it by yourself. But you should **ensure that you have the same (or the closest) version of OpenSSL than the one used for the Qt build**.

- You can check what version of OpenSSL was used for the Qt build with:

```
qDebug() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
```

- You can check if SSL is supported with:

```
qDebug() << QSslSocket::supportsSsl();
```

- You can check what version you have with:

```
qDebug() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
```

**Note:** Don't forget to include the install directory to the PATH environment variable to make the *dlls* accessible (or copy the *dlls*).

---

*Let me know if it does not solve your issue so that I can remove this answer to avoid unnecessary noise.*

Comment: I didn't manage to get a correct page layout in a comment so I add a new answer.

Comment: I added "C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL\Win_x64\bin" to the PATH. Works fine ! even if "build" and "installed" version doesn't match exactly: 1.1.1g vs 1.1.1j
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The answers definitely work, but you have to find a nearly exact match of the OpenSSL library that your Qt app requires.

This may not be easy. For various reasons, the guy at https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html seems to be particularly adamant about not supporting older versions of OpenSSL.

I get the point; it really does make sense, but in our case, it was a server side component that did a "Get" to a well known public https location, one single URL only. (An API). There's no real vulnerability with older versions, IMHO, but I realize that is certainly not be true for every app.

What my fix was, was to open up the app in the Visual Studio debugger. (Any debugger that shows demand load DLL's will work). I then hit "Run".

I found that our app, recently compiled by the way, loaded OpenSSL from "Folding at Home" despite the fact I had loaded *every* version of OpenSSL (and verified the path location) on our test box. Wouldn't run.

On my Dev box, I had NEVER loaded OpenSSL, yet the code ran fine.

I added the line of code that @Fareanor suggested (Upvote his answer also!):

```
qDebug() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
```

Our code said: OpenSSL Version needed:  "OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018"

Our code on my Dev box was demand loading:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FAHClient\SSLEAY32.dll
```

Yours may vary.

The FAH client was version 1.0.2o, or DLL module version: 1.0.2.15. The oldest version from the web site was: 1.0.2.21 and would NOT load even if placed directly in the run location (which is always checked before PATH locations).

Once I copied the OpenSSL files from Folding at Home, to the Prod box from my Dev box, suddenly OpenSSL started working in our code.

We also needed these files:
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
zlib1.dll

and those are not documented

Our code is based on an open source project that bundled the Qt library build in a separate "SDK" directory. I found the cmake scripts wouldn't run with VC 2019, or even a patched version of VC 2017, so we've been very reticent to upgrading the QT in it.

Hopefully, if you "do the right thing" and download Qt and build from their sources, you'll be able to bundle a newer OpenSSL with your app. I just wish that were slightly better documented in the Qt side. To be fair, if you do some digging they do mention you'll need OpenSSL, but it's not obvious.

In the event you're trying to get an app running and don't have, or can't upgrade to newer source, this method will at least tell you where the app is getting OpenSSL from.

```
    == John ==
```

Comment: Hi John, thank you for this reply. I will be certainly helpful. I would like to upvote some repsonses but I can't for now (don't have enough reputation).

Comment: Thank you! I hear you - you've got to hang around for a while and answer some questions. I'm in a similar boat! It's amazing how web sites come and go over the years. It's frustrating to build up reputation all over again.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. This was the key for me to figure out my problem. My precompiled version of Qt was built against a slightly newer version of OpenSSL than the build that's shipped with Qt itself, so for some reason it was working on my machine, but not on some of our clients'. All I had to do was to get a more recent version of the OpenSSL DLLs and include those in my installer.

Comment: You're welcome Pablo! Took me a while, it was painful - I'm glad to have saved you some time! Installations are never trivial and usually saved for the end of a project. I hate advising "save your own" but with OpenSSL it looks like that's the safest. It's not, after all, Microsoft code, so it shouldn't go in windows\system32. The fact that it "fails without reason" if you mix versions also shows it's best to copy your own OpenSSL DLL's.

Comment: In chasing this I found that the 
`QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();`

did not work and returned an empty QString.

Using `QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();` however, returned something comprehensible.

This is particularly annoying at the moment due to 5.15 being LTS and most Linux distros being stuck on stupid with 5.11 or 5.12 package versions.  5.12 used 1.0.2 OpenSSL and 5.15 uses v 1.1.1. Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: @guitarpicva Interesting - did OpenSSL load before you checked the `sslLibraryVersionString`? That was my case. Maybe that means it hadn't loaded, but needed a different version that wasn't available? 

I agree with you, it's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

*Go to: Qt5.12.2\Tools\mingw730_64\opt\bin directory
ssleay_x64.dll
libeay_x64.dll
Copy those libs to the program directory.*

this worked for me. I copied the specified files _x64 version and finally working. Copying other files didn't work for me.