# Incompatible version of OpenSSL on Fedora Linux

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

Am struggling to use ssl with QWebSocket.  Get the following error messages:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
qt.tlsbackend.ossl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL (built with OpenSSL 1.x, runtime version is >= 3.x)
qt.network.ssl: The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslKey
qt.network.ssl: Active TLS backend does not support key creation
qt.network.ssl: The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslKey
qt.network.ssl: Active TLS backend does not support key creation
qt.network.ssl: The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslKey
qt.network.ssl: Active TLS backend does not support key creation
qt.network.ssl: The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslKey
qt.network.ssl: Active TLS backend does not support key creation
WSInterface::onError(): Got the web-socket connection error:  QAbstractSocket::UnsupportedSocketOperationError
```

Using Qt 6.4.2 installed from the Qt Installer as binaries (not built from source) on Fedora 37 on Intel with gcc 12.2

QSslSocket::supportsSsl() return false.

/usr/lib64 is holding:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 430944 Nov 18 08:51 libssl3.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     15 Nov  2 00:41 libssl.so -> libssl.so.3.0.5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     15 Nov  2 00:41 libssl.so.3 -> libssl.so.3.0.5
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 677480 Nov  2 00:41 libssl.so.3.0.5
```

I can't see any ssl (or even references to libssl using ldd in the Qt directories)

If I add /usr/lib64 to the front of LD_LIBRARY_PATH the application sig faults on:

```
this->WebSocket = new QWebSocket();
```

Since the Qt Maintenance Tool provides the source code for OpenSSL 1.1.1q, I downloaded that and built it using the following commands.  Build and install was smooth:

```
sudo dnf group install 'Development Tools' -y
sudo dnf install perl-core zlib-devel -y
cd ~/Qt/Tools/OpenSSL/src
./config --prefix=/usr/lib64 --openssldir=/usr/lib64 shared zlib
make -j8
make test
sudo make install
```

make install added the following files to /usr/lib64

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     29 Jul 22 02:33 libevent_openssl-2.1.so.7 -> libevent_openssl-2.1.so.7.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  36840 Jul 22 02:33 libevent_openssl-2.1.so.7.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     28 Oct 24 18:02 libxmlsec1-openssl.so -> libxmlsec1-openssl.so.1.2.34
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     28 Oct 24 18:02 libxmlsec1-openssl.so.1 -> libxmlsec1-openssl.so.1.2.34
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 304712 Oct 24 18:02 libxmlsec1-openssl.so.1.2.34
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  10909 Jan 10 18:43 openssl.cnf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  10909 Jan 10 18:43 openssl.cnf.dist

ossl-modules:
total 1736
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      38 Jan  8 18:32 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 173 root root  118784 Jan 10 18:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 1488504 Nov  2 00:41 fips.so
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root  120392 Nov  2 00:41 legacy.so
```

This did not seem to change the result - same error messages when running the application; same sig fault when adding /usr/lib64 in front of LD_LIBRARY_PATH

There seems to no mention on how to proceed in the help.  Qt Forum / Bugs and Stackoverflow seem to have lots of articles.  Besides the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and building from source the other suggestion seems to be install openssl 1.1.1 from the package manager.

```
sudo dnf install openssl-1.1.1q-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm
```

Can't find the .rpm.  If I download it from:

```
https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/35/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/o/openssl-1.1.1l-2.fc35.x86_64.rpm
```

then Fedora refuses to install it.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is "Using Qt 6.4.2 installed from the Qt Installer ... on Fedora 37". Linux distributions are assembled using compatible software libraries, precisely for this reason: to avoid these compatibility issues. There are no workarounds. Also manual installing software libraries, in this fashion, carries a high risk of overwriting existing system libraries, turning the entire system into a useless brick. Linux should be reinstalled from scratch to get a stable system. Manual installation of highly complicated software libraries, like Qt, requires expert-level development experience.

Comment: @myk Qt doesn't provide the OpenSSL dependency with it, you need to install it by yourself. To make it work, you need to install the same (or the closest) version than the one that was used for the Qt build that you have installed (you don't need to rebuild Qt, except if you want a specific version of OpenSSL, other than the one used for your actual build).
You may be interested by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626558/11455384) on the topic (where I had similar issues with OpenSSL support).

Comment: Thanks Frareanor.  Your and Sam's comments helped me to solve this.  Used the command: sudo dnf groupinstall "KDE Plasma Workspaces" -q
 Which installs libssl.so.1.1 into /usr/lib64/lib.  Addding this path in-front of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH resolved the errors.